# Pyside qwebview custom protocol

Tags: pyside, qwebview, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'd like to support custom protocol inside my pyside app but without success. So far I tried:

```
class MainWindow(QWebView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        oldManager = self.page().networkAccessManager()
        self.page().setNetworkAccessManager(NetworkAccessManager(self, oldManager))

#in another file
class NetworkAccessManager(QNetworkAccessManager):
    def __init__(self, parent, oldManager):
        QNetworkAccessManager.__init__(self)
        self.oldManager = oldManager
        self.setCache(oldManager.cache())
        self.setCookieJar(oldManager.cookieJar())
        self.setProxy(oldManager.proxy())
        self.setProxyFactory(oldManager.proxyFactory())
        print('There')

    def createRequest(self, operation, request, data):
        print('And there')
```

This results in a `segmentation fault`under windows. I saw [this](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtWebKit/QWebPage.html?highlight=qwebpage#PySide.QtWebKit.PySide.QtWebKit.QWebPage.setNetworkAccessManager) :

> It is currently not supported to change the network access manager after the PySide.QtWebKit.QWebPage has used it.

But I don't see where it would be used in this case. I tried to set a web page object after setting the network manager and 
the segmentation fault disappeared.

PS: none of the print statement is displayed inside the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If createRequest doesn't return a reply it crahes. So the complete solution is:

```
class MainWindow(QWebView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        oldManager = self.page().networkAccessManager()
        self.setPage(DebugWebPage()) #if you want to set a custom page
        self.page().setNetworkAccessManager(NetworkAccessManager(self))

class NetworkAccessManager(QNetworkAccessManager):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QNetworkAccessManager.__init__(self)

    def createRequest(self, operation, request, data):
        if request.url().scheme() != 'page':
            return QNetworkAccessManager.createRequest(self, operation, request, data)

        if operation == self.GetOperation:
            # Handle page:// URLs separately by creating custom
            # QNetworkReply objects.
            reply = PageReply(self, request.url(), self.GetOperation)
            print('here')
            return reply
        else:
            return QNetworkAccessManager.createRequest(self, operation, request, data)

class PageReply(QNetworkReply):
    def __init__(self, parent, url, operation):
        QNetworkReply.__init__(self, parent)
        self.content = '<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>This is a test.</body></html>'
        self.offset = 0

        self.setHeader(QNetworkRequest.ContentTypeHeader, 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
        self.setHeader(QNetworkRequest.ContentLengthHeader, len(self.content))
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self, SIGNAL('readyRead()'))
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self, SIGNAL('finished()'))
        self.open(self.ReadOnly | self.Unbuffered)
        self.setUrl(url)

    def abort(self):
        pass

    def bytesAvailable(self):
        return len(self.content) - self.offset + QNetworkReply.bytesAvailable(self)

    def isSequential(self):
        return True

    def readData(self, maxSize):
        if self.offset < len(self.content):
            end = min(self.offset + maxSize, len(self.content))
            data = self.content[self.offset:end]
            self.offset = end
            return data
```

Note: I don't really know why but any error while the script is in the network manager or the reply results in a segmentation fault.

Based on [this](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Using%20a%20Custom%20Protocol%20with%20QtWebKit) with some correction.